# How to validate unique attributes in nested elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, nested, unique

I have a xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CategoryDeclaration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Category CategoryId="1" DislayText="CategoryName1">
    <Category CategoryId="123" DislayText="CategoryName2">
      <ErrorType DislayText="text1" ErrorTypeId="123" />
      <ErrorType DislayText="text2" ErrorTypeId="222" />  
    </Category>
  </Category>
  <Category CategoryId="1" DislayText="CategoryName1">
     <ErrorType DislayText="text2" ErrorTypeId="222" />  
  </Category>
</CategoryDeclaration>
```

**The attributes CategoryId and ErrorTypeId should be unique in the entire xml file**, but don´t get it working. The category elements can be nested unlimeted.

Here is my xsd, only working for elements in the same level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Category"> 
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">    
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Category" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element ref="ErrorType" minOccurs="0" />
      </xsd:choice>
      <xsd:attribute name="CategoryId" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:attribute name="DislayText" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:unique name="UniqueCategoryId">
       <xsd:selector xpath="Category" /> 
       <xsd:field xpath="@CategoryId" /> 
    </xsd:unique>   
  </xsd:element> 
  <xsd:element name="ErrorType">    
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">  
      <xsd:attribute name="ErrorTypeId" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:attribute name="DislayText" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>      
  <xsd:element name="CategoryDeclaration">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Category" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>   
  </xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `xpath=".//Category"` to select at any level.

Also if the constraint applies to the whole document you could put it on the `CategoryDeclaration` rather than the `Category`, to avoid redundant checking within every category.

Answer (score 0):

Here the working XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Category"> 
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">    
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Category" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element ref="ErrorType" minOccurs="0" />
      </xsd:choice>
      <xsd:attribute name="CategoryId" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:attribute name="DislayText" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element> 
  <xsd:element name="ErrorType">    
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">  
      <xsd:attribute name="ErrorTypeId" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:attribute name="DislayText" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>      
  <xsd:element name="CategoryDeclaration">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="Category" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:unique name="UniqueCategoryId">
       <xsd:selector xpath=".//Category" /> 
       <xsd:field xpath="@CategoryId" /> 
    </xsd:unique>   
    <xsd:unique name="UniqueErrorTypeId">
       <xsd:selector xpath=".//ErrorType" /> 
       <xsd:field xpath="@ErrorTypeId" /> 
    </xsd:unique>   
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```